# How to incorporate legend as plot of plot size when arranging multiple plots using patchwork?

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

Dummy code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

plot1 <- mpg %>% ggplot()
plot2 <- mpg %>% ggplot()
plot3 <- mpg %>% ggplot(aes(cyl, displ)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = manufacturer)) + 
  guides(colour=guide_legend(ncol=4))

(plot1 + plot2) / plot3
```

I'm not looking for a combined legend, but something which looks like:

[image]

Where the legend is 'considered' part of the plot. I've tried adding in margins with `theme()` and `plot_spacer()` but it's not exactly what I want. This is what I get:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your example code one option would be to make use of `guide_area()` like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(magrittr)

plot1 <- mpg %>% ggplot()
plot2 <- mpg %>% ggplot()
plot3 <- mpg %>% ggplot(aes(cyl, displ)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = manufacturer)) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(ncol=3))

plot1 + plot2 + plot3 + guide_area() + 
  plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
```

[image]

Another option would be to extract the guide via `cowplot::get_legend` and add it to the patchwork like so:

```r
(plot1 + plot2) / (plot3 + guides(color = "none") + cowplot::get_legend(plot3))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>